# Oracle select query taking long time

Tags: c#, oracle

This is my select query.

```
    select count(m.uniq_no) cnt
      from web_cst_mst m
inner join WEB_CST_INV i on M.UNIQ_NO=I.UNIQ_NO 
where I.INV_NO='inv01'
  and I.INV_DT=to_date('2015-01-12','YYYY-MM-DD')
  and M.sel_tin='19320703277'
    ;
```

I have created an index for `(uniq_no,sel_tin)` for `web_cst_mst` table and an index for `(uniq_no,inv_no,inv_dt)` for `web_cst_inv` table.

This query is taking around 250ms to execute. Earlier it used to take 500ms when i had trim function for seller `tin(trim(M.sel_tin))`. I removed trim and it's taking half of the original time so i am thinking if i can remove to_date function then it might take lesser time but the problem i am facing here is i am sending a date in string format as i cannot send `c#` date variable in `(10-JAN-14)` this format because the `c#` date variable holds time as well. I have tried the below code just to send the date part so that i can remove to_date function in oracle but it is not working. And the dates in oracle are stored in `(dd-MMM-yy ex:10-JAN-14)` format. So either i have to send only the date part or have to_date function in the query.

I want to send only the date part of datetime variable to increase the performance of this query. But i am not able to achieve that.

Any suggestions/help to improve the performance. Thank you.

```
DateTime inv_date = DateTime.ParseExact(inv_dt, "dd-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;
```

Comment: You *should* use parameterized queries and pass actual DateTime values instead of strings, to avoid conversion errors. For example, the format you mention (`10-JAN-14`) are guaranteed to fail *and* introduce the Y2K bug. That *won't* help with performance though. `to_date` is applied to a single string that can be used to search into an index. `Trim` on the other hand must be applied to *all* rows, preventing the use of indexes.

Comment: Have you looked at the sql execution plan ?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Use bind variables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/building_odp.htm)
2. Create index for INV_NO, INV_DT, sel_tin
3. [Collect statistics on index](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#CIHBIEII)